# \rowcolor does not paint \multicolumn cells

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn, rowcolor

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rX}
Right Right Right & Text \\ 
Right Right Right & Text \\ 
\rowcolor{red}   
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Center}} & \\
Right Right Right  &{\small \rule{0pt}{3ex}} Small space \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

For me this displays as [image]

How can I make the *whole* row red instead of just the second-column part of the row, i.e. "Center" should also be red?

(Note: If a solution is very complicated because of the `multicolumn` (without that it displayes just fine), is there then any other way to make `Center` be at the center of its cell?)

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is here. The whole row *is* red.

Comment: @AlanMunn Please see my edit.

Comment: I see the picture, but you haven't changed the code, and for me the whole row is red. (TL 2017).  Perhaps you have an outdated version of something?  Add `\listfiles` to the document and post the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

`\rowcolor{...}` doesn't coloring cells in `\multicolumn`, so in it you need to additional define cell color with `\cellcolor{...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rX}
Right Right Right & Text \\
Right Right Right & Text \\
\rowcolor{red}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{red}{\textbf{Center}}} & \\ % added cellcolor in multicolum
Right Right Right  &{\small \rule{0pt}{3ex}} Small space \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Here something very weird happens. Now I can't reproduce OP's problem, provided MWE works fine without added `\cellcolor` in `\multicoumn` cell. Frankly said, now I'm confused about what is going on (see comments below).

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I didn't check `colortbl` yet, but my experiences show, that celss in `\multicolumn{...` are hidden to `\rowcolor`, so you need to color this `multicolumn` cell again with `\cellcolor`.

Comment: Weird, because it works fine without `\cellcolor` for me.

Comment: @AlanMunn, yes, it is really weird. When I first time test OP MWE, it gives me result as (s)he show in question, but now I can't reproduce this result. all row is read without adding `cellcolor`. But as I mentioned in my answer, similar result has been happen to me too, and I solve the problem as I show in answer, but never deeply investigate this "phenomena". Now I'm confused ... (and temporary haven't time to investigate, whats going on. maybe tomorow evening, when my planed travel will finish).